# RecycleView Kotlin with ArrayList always size =0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecycleView` with Kotlin that uses `ArrayList`. Here is the code:

```
class TestProvider(val text: ArrayList<String> , val context:Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<TestProvider.holder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): holder {

       return holder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.testitem,parent,false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return text.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: holder, position: Int) {

        holder.txtText.text=text[position]
    }


    class holder(item:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        var txtText:TextView=item.findViewById(R.id.txtTest)
    }
}
```

```xml
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtTest"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

```
     var task1="abdef"
    internal var dateStart: Date? = null
        internal var dateEnd: Date? = null
        var taskProvider: Provider= Provider()
        var TaskList= ArrayList<String>()
        lateinit var taskAdapter: TestProvider
            TaskList.add(0,task1)
            TaskList.add(task1)
            TaskList.add(task1)
           taskAdapter = TestProvider(TaskList,this)
            rcvTest.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
            rcvTest.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            rcvTest.setHasFixedSize(true)
            rcvTest.adapter = taskAdapter
           taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

text in `RecycleView` always size=0.

Comment: Hellp Nguyễn Trường and welcome to the community. could you provide a little more code, e.g. where you initialize the TaskList, or the layout snippet of your recycler view?

Comment: if I could answer your question, please consider marking the answer with the checkmark as the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to rebuild your app, and experienced, that your Adapter seems to be wrong. 
please change the class declaration to:

```
class TestProvider(val text: ArrayList<String>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TestProvider.holder>() {
```

also, your testitem layout should be wrap_content in height, since one item would take the whole screen otherwise